# How to get counter value and store it to the Fragment Text View

Tags: android, kotlin, handler, android-databinding, android-lifecycle

I want to get variable counter value from AppTimer class, and then store every counter change in fragment text view.

Question: How do I get counter value, pass it to fragment then take that value and set to text view in same fragment?

**AppTimer.kt**

```
class AppTimer(lifecycle: Lifecycle) : LifecycleObserver {

    var counter = 0

    /**
     * [Handler] is a class meant to process a queue of messages (known as [android.os.Message]s)
     * or actions (known as [Runnable]s)
     */
    private var handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private lateinit var runnable: Runnable

    // connection between fragment and observer(timer)
    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun startTimer() {
        // Create the runnable action, which prints out a log and increments the seconds counter
        runnable = Runnable {
            counter ++
            Timber.i("Timer is at : $counter ")
            // postDelayed re-adds the action to the queue of actions the Handler is cycling
            // through. The delayMillis param tells the handler to run the runnable in
            // 1 second (1000ms)
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
        }

        // This is what initially starts the timer
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)

        // Note that the Thread the handler runs on is determined by a class called Looper.
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun stopTimer() {
        // Removes all pending posts of runnable from the handler's queue, effectively stopping the
        // timer
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }
}
```

**Fragment.kt**

```
class AppFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var appTimer: AppTimer

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        appTimer = AppTimer(this.lifecycle)

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentAppBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_app, container, false)
        Timber.i("onCreateView Called")
        return binding.root
    }

   
}
```